# Wrap specflow scenario within try-catch

Tags: c#, selenium, specflow

I have been running into a problem with the C# selenium bindings decribed here: [Selenium Error - The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver timed out after 60 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22322596/)

where a timeout exception is thrown occasionally while running my selenium tests. The tests are all written using spec flow, and I would love to have a way to catch that exception and have the test return as Inconclusive (instead of failed) for that particular exception.

Does anyone know of a way to wrap each spec flow scenario in a try catch block? Is that possible to do? Or a way to automatically catch this exception without having to wrap each individual step definition in a try catch block?

Thanks!

Comment: Yikes. This sounds bad. I would want those tests to fail. What if a test times out, gets marked "inconclusive", and would have encountered a bug. A developer looks at the test report and goes "oh, we have one inconclusive test, no failures. Let's ship the code." This is how bugs make it to production.

Comment: My workflow involves my triaging failed / inconclusive tests before releasing anything.  To me, inconclusive means just that -- not enough info to know if it's a real failure or not.  In this case, the test is either failing from instability or an actual bug -- there's not a way to know without further investigation.  So marking it as inconclusive makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a workaround for this issue where I can check for the exception after each step using the [AfterStep] binding.  This works for me, and tests that failed are now marked as inconclusive:

```
[AfterStep]
    public void check()
    {
        var exception = ScenarioContext.Current.TestError;
        if (exception is WebDriverException 
            && exception.Message.Contains("The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL "))
        {
            Assert.Inconclusive(exception.Message);
        }
    }
```

Hopefully someone finds this helpful!