# C# selenium HTTP request to the remote web driver server for URL timed out after 60 seconds

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iis-6

Chrome driver stopped working for Chrome browser version 55 with the latest Chrome driver 2.24 and  Web Driver 2.48.

I am getting the error "HTTP request to the remote web driver server for URL timed out after 60 seconds"

some months back i faced the same issue, i followed the same suggestion as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22322596/selenium-error-the-http-request-to-the-remote-webdriver-timed-out-after-60-sec), it worked well till chrome version 54.

Can you suggest for Chrome version 55

Note: Its working fine in local, not working when hosting in IIS

Comment: I have chrome 55 selenium.support 2.53 selenium.webdriver 2.53 it look that is work fine.

Comment: what about Chrome driver version?

Comment: ChromeDriver 2.24.417431

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Chrome in the standalone package that you downloaded instead of your system installation.You can do this by:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.BinaryLocation = @"path\\to\\the\\standalone\\chrome.exe"; 
  // chrome installation exe
```

for : [more](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=46)

Comment: Its worked for me. Thanks a lot. I have used chrome version 53 exe in binary location. if we use chrome version 55 then its not working.

Comment: If you put @"" why bother adding double //, that's the whole point of using @ before a string.