# The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:6444/session timed out after 60 seconds

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I am currently facing a problem in initializing Firefox in selenium. This issue seems to be only happening to me on Windows Server 2012 r2 as I have tried the same configuration on my local machine (windows 10) and it worked without a problem.

I am currently using this code (C#):

```
 FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService("Path to Drivers folder", "geckodriver.exe");
                    service.Port = 6444;
                    service.FirefoxBinaryPath = "Firefox installation path";
                    ffDriver = new FirefoxDriver(service);
```

However, it is returning this error:

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote
>   WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:6444/session timed out after
>   60 seconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out

Current versions being used:

- Firefox 56.0 64bit
- Selenium 3.5.1
- Geckodriver v0.19.0 64bit

Can someone please guide me through this issue?

Comment: Are you using firefoxprofile

Comment: @iamsankalp89 I have added this line:

FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(); 

However, the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in code on Launching FirefoxDriver

By referencing this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22322596/selenium-error-the-http-request-to-the-remote-webdriver-timed-out-after-60-sec)

```
  ffDriver=   new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxBinary(),new FirefoxProfile(),TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I tried that but it didnt work.

For it to work I had to create a process of the geckodriver on the server.

Comment: Okay let me try other ones