# Selenium IE driver hangs after navigating to URL

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xunit.net, selenium-iedriver

I have simple Selenium xUnit Test as below

```
    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(@"C:\Users\myusername\.nuget\packages\selenium.webdriver.iedriver\3.150.1\driver");

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");

        var q = driver.FindElementByName("q");
        q.SendKeys("Stackoverflow");
    }
```

When i run test. it  opens IE11 browser, goes to url, in this case it goes to `www.google.com` and thats it.
After navigating to the URL it does not execute the next line of code, which is `var q = driver.FindElementByName("q");`

and after 60 seconds it throws error

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'The HTTP request to the remote
>   WebDriver server for URL
>   http://localhost:64515/session/4240d446-303f-40b4-b25e-6d7161b2ac73/url
>   timed out after 60 seconds.'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL ... timed out after 60 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54522602/the-http-request-to-the-remote-webdriver-server-for-url-timed-out-after-60-s)

Comment: I have the same issue..

Comment: did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a "Wait" command before the "FindElementByName", there is a chance that this line is executed before the element is shown.

Comment: As i said the next statement afetr `Goto()` does not get executed. So putting `wait` after `Goto()` would not help barbecue it never executes. ( I tried btw with no luck)