# How to Run C# Selenium program in a Docker Linux container

Tags: c#, selenium, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Using `dotnet` tools, I can build a C# project and run it by using the DLL.

- `dotnet clean`
- `dotnet build -c "Release" .`
- `dotnet ./SeleniumSample/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.0/SeleniumSample.dll`

However, when I try to replicate this in a docker container, I am faced with multiple issues:

1. Loading ChromeDriver
2. Loading Chrome in headless mode

So far, I have not found samples of the combination ["C#" , "Selenium", "Docker"] anywhere else in the internet. So, I would love it if you could help me.

Snipplet of loading the Chrome Driver:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--headless");
driver = new ChromeDriver(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), options);
```

***Note:*** `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` will point to the directory containing `chromedriver.exe` generated by the build using `dotnet` cli.

Contents of **SeleniumSample.csproj** is shown below:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release;ALL</Configurations>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver" Version="0.20.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver" Version="3.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver" Version="2.38.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**Dockerfile** contents:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
COPY ${source} .
RUN dotnet clean
RUN dotnet build -c "Release"
WORKDIR ./SeleniumSample/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.0/
ENTRYPOINT dotnet ./SeleniumSample.dll
```

Code to execute the container of the created image is below after `docker-compose up`:

```
docker run -i -t -P -v /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 \ 
-v /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 \ 
-v /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss3.so:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss3.so \ 
-v /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnssutil3.so:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnssutil3.so \ 
-v /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnspr4.so:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnspr4.so \ 
-v /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 \ 
-v /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libplc4.so:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libplc4.so \ 
-v /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libplds4.so:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libplds4.so \ 
-v /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 \ 
-v /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 \ 
seleniumsample_selenium-sample
```

The following error occurs:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb) on port 40599
Only local connections are allowed.

Unhandled Exception: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Linux 4.13.0-41-generic x86_64)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   at SeleniumSample.Utility.GetDriver(String browserName, String argument) in /app/SeleniumSample/Utility.cs:line 54
   at SeleniumSample.GmailUnreadEmails.Launcher() in /app/SeleniumSample/GmailUnreadEmails.cs:line 80
   at SeleniumSample.Launcher.Main(String[] args) in /app/SeleniumSample/Launcher.cs:line 8
Aborted (core dumped)
```

My guess is the `Chrome` is not installed in the docker image and so I am getting this error. If that is true, how do I fix this problem?

**EDIT 1**:
after adding the below lines to the Dockerfile

```
RUN \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y wget

RUN \
  wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - && \
  echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
WORKDIR /data
EXPOSE 5901
```

Now I get the below error-

```
selenium-sample_1  | Only local connections are allowed.
selenium-sample_1  | 
selenium-sample_1  | Unhandled Exception: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:45521/session timed out after 60 seconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out.
```

*After this edit, the question becomes similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22322596/selenium-error-the-http-request-to-the-remote-webdriver-timed-out-after-60-sec?noredirect=1&lq=1) question but it is still worth having on the site because no one else has tried such a scenario to the best of my knowledge.*

Comment: If I had to guess, based on the error message, it is looking for the linux chrome binary which is not chromedriver.exe. I would try with the linux binary here:http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: But if I wanted to run this on a Continuous Integration Server or Simply on Docker itself then it should be able to execute without hard coded links to the local machine, right?

Comment: I believe if the driver was not found, I would have gotten an error like this, right?  `Unhandled Exception: OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException: The chromedriver file does not exist in the current directory or in a directory on the PATH environment variable.`

Comment: No @John, I did not install chrome using Dockerfile but I did launch into the image after removing the `ENTRYPOINT` in `Dockerfile` and tried to install chrome using the instructions provided here (https://askubuntu.com/a/510186/270827) and then ran `dotnet ./SeleniumSample.dll` on it but that did not solve the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22322596/selenium-error-the-http-request-to-the-remote-webdriver-timed-out-after-60-sec?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Wrong question was marked as the redirect link please look at the one above for the solution